# How does the golang scheduler sched goroutine in following code?

Tags: go, scheduling, goroutine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "runtime"
)

var quit chan int = make(chan int)

func loop(a int) {
    fmt.Println(a)
    for i := 0; i < 30000000000; i++ {
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
    quit <- 0
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go loop(1)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    go loop(2)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        <-quit
    }
}
```

For the scheduler model (M+P+G), I suppose we just have 1 cpu context because we set `GOMAXPROCS` as 1, and there is just 1 thread(M) here.

In the goroutine, the for loop do not has any IO blocking, so no new thread will be generated, all goroutine should still work in current thread, so I think the 2 goroutine must go one by one, thus, the result should be `1 1 2 2`. But in fact, the result is `1 2 1 2`. Why?

Comment: Goroutines don't map directly to threads, meaning you can run as many as you want on a a single thread. They wouldn't be much use for concurrency if they couldn't run concurrently.

Comment: @JimB As I know, all G(goroutine) will added to P(context)'s local queue, P will attach M(os thread), then if G has IO blocking, then P will detech from current M and produce a new M to attach with current P, the following G will run in P with new M. Here we just have 1 M, as goroutine in fact still a coroutine, next go routine could seize the chance to run unless the before goroutine give up the cpu with PARK or GoSched, here, the goroutine did not do that, why the second goroutine has the chance to seize the CPU?

Comment: @JimB I know a lot of goroutine could run on one thread, but they should cooperate to seize the cpu, if one did not give up CPU, all goroutine on this thread should block? Is my unstanding wrong. If correct, why above code, the second goroutine get the CPU? Did some opeation in my goroutine indeed give up CPU and make go scheduler reschedule? Please suggest, thanks.

Comment: Like you said, they don't yield the CPU during the busy loop, the first loop yields at the entry to the `fmt.Println` call, which is why the second `1 2` is printed in quick succession.

Comment: @JimB Yes, I have once heard about that fmt.Println will give up CPU, it seems it is the root cause as you are the second guy point this. I am a newbie to golang. If Println give up CPU, how can I prove if my understanding is correct or not as Println will change the logic, any good method for me to use rather than Print? I want to know if my understanding to golang schduelr logic is true or not, I need experiment.

Comment: it's not specifically `fmt.Println`, it's that function calls, IO, and channel operations are all scheduling points. You can prove that a busy loop blocks the entire thread by making it an infinite loop and seeing that no progress is made. Other than the fact that a busy loop is a programming error, I'm not sure what you're trying to prove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the order of the relevant operations in your program.

1. `go loop(1)` dispatches goroutine loop1
2. `time.Sleep(time.Second)` starts in the `main` goroutine
3. `fmt.Println(a)` called from loop1, **prints `1`**
4. loop1 enters busy loop and holds the CPU
5. entry to `fmt.Println(a)` from loop1 yields to the scheduler
6. `main` goroutine wakes up, finishes the `time.Sleep` call
7. `go loop(2)` dispatches goroutine loop2
8. `fmt.Println(a)` called from loop2, **prints `2`**
9. loop2 enters busy loop and holds the CPU
10. entry to `fmt.Println(a)` from loop2 yields to the scheduler
11. loop1 one wakes up and finishes `fmt.Println(a)`, **prints `1`**
12. loop1 sends `0` over the quit channel
13. loop2 finishes `fmt.Println(a)`, **prints `2`**
14. loop2 sends `0` over the quit channel